# I need help with these inequalities and if tests, not sure how to solve

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, graphing-functions

Alright, so let's say you have this problem:

$$x = -2\text{ and }x = 3\\
y = \begin{cases}2x + 3 &    \text{if }x < 0\\
                 2x + 5 &    \text{if }x > 0
    \end{cases}$$

So do you look at the if statement, then plug it in if $x$ works? For example, for the first condition, I look at $x < 0$. Do I only pick out $-2$, because it's only true for that, then solve? That would make my final answer $f(-2) = -1$, correct?

OR...

Do I plug all of them in, then write the solution if the final answer applies? I'm really confused someone please help me.

Comment: who -1 my question?

Comment: I asked it because I was sincerely confused, not to receive negative feedback.

Comment: I don't blame you for being confused.  The sentence "x = -2 and x = 3" doesn't make any sense by itself and nowhere does the question tell us what we are supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you check the condition on $x$ and use the formula that applies. By the way, your function is not well defined in general since it doesn't specify what happens if $x=0,$ but maybe you want $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$ as your domain. Assuming you didn't want to include zero
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl} 2x+3, &\mathrm{ if } & x <0 \\ & & \\ 2x+5 &\mathrm{ if} & x> 0\end{array} \right.
$$
So $f(-2)=-1$ and $f(3)=11.$

Comment: no need for the definition of $x=0$, since the OP actually never mentioned the domain...